# Sqlite order by DESC performance

Tags: node.js, sqlite, api

I used nodejs, connect to sqlite db to select data. I had a performance problem when run query with ORDER BY clause. This is my query

1. `this.db.all("SELECT * FROM my_table a WHERE my_condition ORDER BY a.last_visit_day",[])`: It took **280ms**
2. `this.db.all("SELECT * FROM my_table a WHERE my_condition ORDER BY a.last_visit_day DESC", [])`: It took **3s** ? I don't know why it took more time to sort desc

When I run both of these query in sqlite browser application, it took **280ms** only

I have searched google but cannot not find any solutions.

Many thank

Comment: Show us your table schema too.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE [my_table] (
  [id] INTEGER NOT NULL ON CONFLICT FAIL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  [full_name] VARCHAR2(300) NOT NULL, 
  [province_code] VARCHAR2(20), 
  [district_code] VARCHAR2(20), 
  [precinct_code] VARCHAR2(20), 
  [phone] VARCHAR2(20), 
  [birthday] INTEGER, 
  [sex] INT(1),
  [last_visit_date] INTEGER);

CREATE INDEX [my_table_nuk] ON [my_table] ([last_visit_date]);`
That is table schema